# C Language, Switch Statement

Tags: c#, c, switch-statement, conditional-statements

```
 void main()
    {
        printf("     IT Magey      \n");
    
        int code;
    
        printf("\nEnter item code : T");
        scanf("%d", &code);
    
        double price;
        printf("Enter item price : ");
        scanf("%lf", &price);
    
        double dct;
        printf("Enter discount ('%%') : ");
        scanf("%lf", &dct );
    
        char m;
        printf("Enter payment mode (F or I): ");
        scanf("%c \n", &m);
    
        switch (m)
       {
       case 'F':
       case 'f':
        printf("\n");
    
        printf("Payment Details \n");
        printf("-----------------------------\n");
        printf("Item Code : T003256\n");
        printf("Item price: USD 2342.80\n");
    
        double dct1=price*dct/100;
        printf( "Discount: USD%lf \n", dct1);
    
        double amount1=price-dct1;
        printf("Amount to pay: USD%lf", amount1 );
        break;
    
    
       case 'I':
       case 'i':
        printf("\n");
    
        int mth;
        printf("Enter number of installments (months) : ");
        scanf("%d", &mth);
    
        printf("\n");
    
        printf("Payment Details \n");
        printf("-----------------------------\n");
        printf("Item Code : T003256\n");
        printf("Item price: USD 2342.80\n");
    
        double dct2=price*dct/100;
        printf( "Discount: USD%lf \n", dct2);
    
        double amount2=price-dct1;
        printf("Amount to pay: USD%lf", amount2 );
    
        printf("\n");
    
        printf("Number of installments : %d \n", mth);
    
        double amount3=price/mth;
        printf(" Amount to pay per installement : USD%lf", amount3 );
        break;
    
       default:
        printf("Please select only F or I");
    
    
    
    
    
       }
```

Newbie here, my switch statement won't show any output besides the default one. I've added (breaks) to it still the same nevertheless. If there are other issues regarding this program besides the switch statement, do list them out too. Thanks :)

Just started using this site, I'm trying to fill in more details to satisfy the error of having too less details :/

**Edit#1:**
So after changing *switch ('m')* to *switch(m)*, my output is still the same. If I were to try using if..else if, I was expecting my output to only show the 'F' or 'f' code, what I got was everything 'I' and 'i' code included.

Comment: You may find you get more C language programmers if you tag your question with `C` and not `C#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter passed in switch statement is a *character constant* `'m'`, rather than the variable `m` that you want to check.

You have to pass like this:

```c
switch (m) {
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry my bad. It's in character form.

Comment: Aight, I tried it. The output is still the same, it skips to default :/.

Comment: try changing `scanf("%c \n", &m);` to `scanf("%c", &m);`

Answer (score 3):

Clarifying AbdulBasit's answer, which is mostly correct but does not indicate why the code compiles but gives the wrong answer.

As AbdulBasit indicates, `switch ('m')` is using the single character 'm' -- not actually a string per se -- but is totally valid code.

What the code is doing is saying --

- Compare the character 'm' with the values in the following cases and execute the match.
- Compare 'm' with 'F' and 'f'.  Yes, to be hyper accurate this is two cases with fall-through from the first case into the second case.
- No match, try next case.
- Compare 'm' with 'I' and 'i'.
- No match, try next case.
- No next case. Try the default case if it exists.
- Execute the default case -- tell the user they need to enter 'F' or 'I'.

As AbdulBasit indicated, while the `scanf()` does read the user input into the variable `m`, the switch is running comparisons against the constant character `'m'`.

Comment: Yeah hi there, thanks for the additional input. Though, even after changing my code a tad bit, I still get the same output :/